# FAST Search result only show the summary from attachments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, fast

I am facing a issue with FAST Search for SharePoint 2010. We have configured a SharePoint 2007 List content source in FAST, and the list only using for store items like News, notifications. Some items have attachments like Office Word, Excel or txt file. However, when we search some keywords in Search Center, the result for those items have attachment only show the summary inside attachment not the content of item, even if the keyword included in the item content.

I'd like to know if possible to change this behavior and how to?

Comment: If you search for a word in a list column which is not in the attachment, do you get hit highlighting?

Comment: I found the issue and configured the Search Core Webpart to include the custom Managed Porperties. Thank you!